# Android: DTMF Conference call

Tags: android, dtmf, android-dialer

I am working a conference app, in this application I need to call a conference number via Intent Action. The phone number is as "Phone No,Conference Pin#".

The main problem I am facing is after call get connected, to join conference it take 20 sec. If we dial same number via native dialer it took around 10.

What will be the cause for this?

It there any other pause characters to be used, instead of ","?